# Uncaught GaxiosError Error: unauthorized_client

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

## getting Uncaught "GaxiosError Error: unauthorized_client"

[image: token exchange code]
cross checked both front end back end client id
change the API call from get Token from 'googleapis' and 'google-auth-library'
checked with different code

what will be the cause for this issue?
`